# res.send displayed the wrong result but console.log give to the same response the correct result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to display the response by using res.send(), but it throws me a wrong result, but when console.logging that same response it gives me the correct response
(which is not expected).

**Here's the code:**

```
var alldata = wc2014.rounds.concat(wc2018.rounds);
   
    for(i = 0; i < alldata.length; i++){
      var a = alldata[0].matches;
      var b = alldata[1].matches;
      var result = a.concat(b);
    }

   
   for (var key in result) {
      if(result[key].goals1.length > result[key].goals2.length){
        var team1 = result[key].team1.name; 
        console.log(team1);
      }
      else{
        var team2 = result[key].team2.name;
        console.log(team2); 
      }
    }  

    res.send(team1 || team2);
```

**console.log**

> Germany
> France

**res.send()**

> France

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this outside of your "for" loop :

```
console.log(team1)
console.log(team2)
console.log(team1 || team2)
```

The rsult would be :

```
France
Germany
France
```

It means team1 value is France and team2 also Germany
"(team1 || team2) " => if team1 is not empty it's equal to team1
If team1 is empty or any falsy value the statement is equal to team2
And because team1 has a value(France)
the res.send (team1 || team2) Is like res.send(team1) and it will send "France" as a response.

Comment: but i also tried this: `for (var key in result) { if(result[key].goals1.length > result[key].goals2.length){var team1 = result[key].team1.name; 
        console.log(team1);res.send(team1);}else{var team2 = result[key].team2.name; console.log(team2); res.send(team2);}}` its not working

Comment: in the end i will pass this data in ejs

Comment: I've tried this and solve the problem:
 `var items = []; for (var key in result) { if(result[key].goals1.length > result[key].goals2.length){var team1 = result[key].team1.name; console.log(team1);}else{var team2 = result[key].team2.name; console.log(team2);}items.push(team1 || team2);} res.render('index',{
data: items
});`  
i use the push() method. The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.